# Can I reload Java Class from another package from an external JAR file?

Tags: java, classloader

I have a requirement for implementation which I am not sure if it is at all possible.

I understand that the class-loaders can help in reloading a class dynamically. Can I use the class-loaders, implement the functionality in a separate java project, then use this jar in existing java projects to replace the existing class in that project.

The goal is to not modify the code in the existing class. However, by proving the new code in a jar, should dynamically replace the existing class with the new class in the JAR file?

Comment: Yes, you can. What is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: I don't know where to start from. Any leads or examples would be appreciated?

Comment: There are plenty of classloader examples online. You can write your own test classloader, register it and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you better idea: [Using a custom ClassLoader to override existing implementations of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389459/using-a-custom-classloader-to-override-existing-implementations-of-classes/66390054)

Create a new loader in your new jar and use -Djava.system.class.loader=my.package.path.NewClassesLoader while running the application. In the loader get byte code from new classes instead of old ones.