# Trying to access a class file inside a package "mypackage" from a java file which is outside "mypackage"

Tags: java, package

MyClass.class

```
package mypackage;

public class MyClass{

    public String getName(String name){
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is MyClass.class which is inside D://javanew/mypackage

Xyz.java

```
import javanew.mypackage.MyClass;

public class Xyz{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String n="Arindam";
        
        MyClass mc=new MyClass();
        
        String name=mc.getName(n);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

This is Xyz.java which is inside d:\javanew.
I want to import MyClass in Xyz.java but when i open cmd and enter d: and write command as
"javac Xyz.java" i am getting the below error:

```
Xyz.java:1: error: cannot access MyClass
import javanew.mypackage.MyClass;
                        ^
  bad source file: .\javanew\mypackage\MyClass.java
    file does not contain class javanew.mypackage.MyClass
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
Xyz.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                MyClass mc=new MyClass();
                ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class Xyz
Xyz.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                MyClass mc=new MyClass();
                               ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class Xyz
```

I know one solution that if i make "package javanew.mypackage" inside MYClass.java then i can access the file inside Xyz.java . I want to know is there any other solution to access the "MyClass" file inside Xyz.java without altering package name of MyClass.java.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389459/using-a-custom-classloader-to-override-existing-implementations-of-classes
If you are a rookie in Java - don't.

Comment: i am a rookie. i don't understand a thing of what you shared

Answer (score 0):

Since the class `Xyz` and the directory `mypackage` is in the same directory which is `javanew`, you should not do `import javanew.mypackage.MyClass` in `Xyz` class. Instead do `import mypackage.MyClass` only in `Xyz` class.

So, the `Xyz` class should be like this:

```
import mypackage.MyClass;

public class Xyz{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String n="Arindam";
        
        MyClass mc=new MyClass();
        
        String name=mc.getName(n);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok..what if Xyz.java was in "D" drive and "MyClass" was in "D:/Javanew/mypackage" ? then how will i import MyClass into Xyz.java?  Im confused in this scenario.

Comment: in Xyz you import javanew.mypackage.MyClass. In MyClass you set the package as package javanew.mypackage;

Comment: ok i got the point. But suppose i have one java file in "Javanew" folder called "Pqr.java" now if i want to import "MyClass.java" from "Pqr.java" again i have to set/change the package to "mypackage" inside MyClass?

So each time i want to import a particular java file from somewhere else. always i have to go and change the package path inside the source java file? 

Comment: Here's the point:  
The package declaration of a class must be the same with its folder path. That's just it. The import statement must be the file path relative to the class that imports another class. That's why you shouldn't import javanew.mypackage.MyClass in Xyz class because The compiler starts searching imported files inside the folder where the  running class is.  The compiler can't see the javanew folder because the compiler begin it's search inside the javanew folder itself.

Comment: ok then what should be my package statement inside MyClass.java? so that i can import the MyClass.java from anywhere?

mypackage folder is inside ThisPc/D/javanew

Comment: This will be my last reply to your comment. Seems like you're not reading my explanation carefully. I think you're better off watching a tutorial on java packages on youtube.