# Can I modify executed code of a static method without changing that class's code or client code?

Tags: java, proxy, classloader

Suppose we have some `Main` class that calls some static method of another class `Foo`. That method prints "foo", but let's imagine I want it to print "bar". But here's the problem: for the reasons I won't delve into, I can't modify the client code (that invokes that method directly) or the `Foo` code

Can I achieve my task?

I was thinking about writing a custom `ClassLoader` that overrides `findClass()` and returns a `Foo` proxy that prints what I want (I guess could use ByteBuddy to generate such a `Class`). But I'm not sure how I can make the JVM pick it up. Does it automatically take anything that extends `ClassLoader` and uses it? Another thing is that `ClassLoader`s delegate. Will my `FooClassLoader` simply delegate to `ApplicationClassLoader` that loads the "real" `Foo` so it won't work?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo.printSomething();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can build your own classLoader. For execution you can use: 
-Djava.system.class.loader=MyCustomClassLoader to make it your default class loader.

Comment: @BarbetNL will it disable `ApplicationClassLoader` completely? I still need it to load the rest of the classes. Also, is there a way that doesn't involve CLI options?

Comment: I haven't tried that myself, I see a question here that tries to do something similar. I guess it can work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389459/using-a-custom-classloader-to-override-existing-implementations-of-classes